# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities with Selenium v3.14.0 and GeckoDriver v0.23.0

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

My versions are selenium-java-3.14.0 and geckodriver-v0.23.0-win64. 
I am using the following code.

```
WebDriver driver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\\\Try out files\\\\geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String baseURL = "http://www.google.com";
driver.get(baseURL);
```

When I run it, I get the following error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:05:20.749Z'
System info: host: '*******', ip: '*****`enter code here`', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:122)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:103)
    at basicweb.FirefoxDriverDemo.main(FirefoxDriverDemo.java:17)
```

Comment: Try updating FF browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use firefox version 56 or 61 and gecko driver version 0.21. and add firefox options  use profile.

```
FirefoxOptions fo = new FirefoxOptions();
fo.setBinary("C:\\Users\\ChawlaSh\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("default");
fo.setProfile(myprofile);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(fo);
```

I hope this will surely help.

Comment: Any reason to ask OP for downgrading _GeckoDriver_?

Comment: I faced same issue month ago and if you check Mozilla release's page on GitHub they have mentioned which gecko driver is compatible with which version of selenium and Firefox for me it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

...implies that your program wasn't able to create a new **Firefox Browser** session..

---

### Analysis

There are a couple of issues as follows:

- `file.separator`: Character that separates components of a file path. This is **`/`** on UNIX and **`\`** on Windows. You need to escape them too.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_151** which is pretty **ancient**.

---

### Solution

- Use `file.separator` as **`\`** escaping with another **`\`**.
- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u191**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Ensure the GeckoDriver-Firefox Mapping

[image: Geckodriver Releases]

- You effective code block will be:

  ```
  WebDriver driver;
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Try out files\\geckodriver.exe");
  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  String baseURL = "http://www.google.com";
  driver.get(baseURL);
  ```